# How to monitor folders visited by a user?

Tags: directory, monitoring

I'm working on a project trying to auto-bookmark folders based on how frequently a folder/directory is visited. I have searched exhaustively as to how to monitor folders visited by the current user. Can anyone guide me as to how to construct a script for doing the same?

Language restrictions : C or Java. Maybe python.

Answer (score 2):

Install `inotify-tools` and you can play around with `inotifywatch` and `inotifywait`. The first logs all activity, the second breaks on certain activity. Both work well but obviously which you want depends on what you're doing.

A simple bash to show the first operation inside a directory is:

```
$ inotifywait -r .
./path/to/ OPEN file.ext
```

Note if it's a big dir, setting up all the listeners takes a while.

For better scripting access, look at [`pyinotify`](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) or just look at the C headers for [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki).